# Contributors tab not showing up on github repo page

Tags: git, github

My repository https://github.com/paolotron/Drop-Hanabi does not show up the contributor tab
in the bottom right corner as usual. What could be the cause?

Comment: I've never saw the contributor tab in the bottom left corner. It's inside [Insights](https://github.com/paolotron/Drop-Hanabi/pulse): https://github.com/paolotron/Drop-Hanabi/graphs/contributors

Comment: Bottom right sorry, https://github.com/mspronesti/baylib like in this example on another repo

Comment: Oh, I see. The middle of the right column. :-)

Comment: Exactly, why it's not showing up?

Comment: No idea. I have a few repositories ([sqlobject](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject), [Cheetah3](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3)) and I don't remember I've done anything special to show contributors. Could it be because your repo is a fork? The list of contributors is shown up in the [source repo](https://github.com/squillero/computational-intelligence).

Comment: I think it's beacuse my repo is a fork and commits to a fork don't count towards contibutions on github, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason was that my repository is a fork and github doesen't count as contributions commits on forked repository, a solution is detaching the repository from the forked project by contacting github support